# can't load iwlwifi nonfree firmware after kernel update

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, iwlwifi

My hardware requires the iwlwifi nonfree firmware for working wifi. With the latest kernel version however it stopped being able to load it. The last working version is 4.9.0-7 while 4.9.0-8 does not work. Is this a bug in the kernel or am I missing something?

Edit: The 4.9.0-8 kernel has the following in kern.log which is not there for the 7 kernel:

```
[    5.488703] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[    5.488707] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: CSR values:
[    5.488709] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[    5.488752] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00489000
[    5.488805] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X0000ff40
[    5.488858] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X80000000
[    5.488911] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[    5.488965] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00010000
[    5.489018] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000010
[    5.489071] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000000
[    5.489121] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X08040005
[    5.489174] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X00000230
[    5.489227] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0Xd55555d5
[    5.489280] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0Xd55555d5
[    5.489333] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0Xd55555d5
[    5.489386] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X001f0042
[    5.489440] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[    5.489493] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[    5.489546] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[    5.489599] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[    5.489652] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000020
[    5.489705] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X8825fe95
[    5.489763] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X07800200
[    5.489884] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0Xd55555d5
[    5.489937] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:      CSR_MONITOR_STATUS_REG: 0Xc03803c0
[    5.489990] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[    5.490043] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0000
[    5.490046] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH register values:
[    5.490109] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X25fd0000
[    5.490173] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X026011b0
[    5.490237] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X00000008
[    5.490302] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80801054
[    5.490366] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X000000fc
[    5.490430] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X07030000
[    5.490494] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[    5.490558] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X07ff0001
[    5.490622] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[    5.490787] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.490790] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    5.490793] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 22.361476.0
[    5.490796] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001245 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    5.490799] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    5.490801] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    5.490804] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00005386 | branchlink2
[    5.490807] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x000111F4 | interruptlink1
[    5.490809] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[    5.490812] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[    5.490815] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data2
[    5.490817] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x000000A1 | data3
[    5.490820] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x003FD349 | beacon time
[    5.490823] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00002CB5 | tsf low
[    5.490825] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    5.490828] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    5.490830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00002CB6 | time gp2
[    5.490833] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[    5.490836] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000016 | uCode version major
[    5.490839] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00058404 | uCode version minor
[    5.490841] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000230 | hw version
[    5.490844] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00489000 | board version
[    5.490847] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0911016A | hcmd
[    5.490849] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00022080 | isr0
[    5.490852] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    5.490855] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x28201802 | isr2
[    5.490857] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x404001C0 | isr3
[    5.490860] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    5.490862] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x04800118 | last cmd Id
[    5.490865] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[    5.490868] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000E7FF | l2p_control
[    5.490870] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    5.490873] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    5.490876] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    5.490878] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000008F | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    5.490881] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x03071928 | timestamp
[    5.490884] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000820 | flow_handler
[    5.491054] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    5.491056] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    5.491059] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000070 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    5.491062] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    5.491065] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0082F64 | umac branchlink2
[    5.491067] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0081000 | umac interruptlink1
[    5.491070] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0081000 | umac interruptlink2
[    5.491073] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000800 | umac data1
[    5.491075] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0081000 | umac data2
[    5.491078] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    5.491081] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000016 | umac major
[    5.491083] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00058404 | umac minor
[    5.491086] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886280 | frame pointer
[    5.491089] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886280 | stack pointer
[    5.491091] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0911016A | last host cmd
[    5.491094] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    5.495595] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Comment: Since you can have both kernels installed, you can compare the relevant portions of boot logs (dmesg or /var/log/kern.log) related to wifi to see what's different across reboot. If you did, then add the relevant portions in the question.

Comment: added kernel log of failure

Comment: Well that's strange considering that changing the -7- to -8- usually at Debian just means an ABI break (<=> external modules most be recompiled), config options are almost identical. You could try upgrading firmware-iwlwifi to stretch-backports 's version, and possibly also the linux-image-amd64 (which is currently pointing there to a kernel v 4.19.12)

Comment: of course a bug report at debian should be considered